# WWW Folder empty while run android --prod in ionic 5

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ionic4

How to solve this error in ionic 5 i tried removing platform and add again but once problem is solved and then again it comes

[Click Here for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BAch.png)

Comment: what corodva version are you using?

Comment: "cordova-android": "^9.0.0", @NajamUsSaqib